# Evaluate the integral in closed form

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I saw a proposed integral [here](https://www.facebook.com/groups/355300697927549/permalink/2488119687978962/?app=fbl) which says to evaluate $$\int_{15}^{16}\frac{\sqrt{x-15}}{\sqrt{x}\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}\right)}\,dx$$
Integration by parts gives the integral with the following form $$4\log(2^{5/2})-2\int_{15}^{16}\frac{\log\left(2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}\right)}{\sqrt{x-15}}\,dx$$
The last integral seems divergent at lower integral point however,  WA provides the the approximation for it [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5BIntegrate+1%2F2*log%282sqrt%282%29%2Bsqrt%284%2Bsqrt%28x%29%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28x-15%29%29+15+to+16%5D).
I got stuck from the last integral we obtained by IBP. Is IBP is correct to evaluate  the integral?

Comment: At the lower endpoint your integrand behaves as $(x-15)^{-1/2}$. That's an integrable singularity and therefore not problematic for purposes of convergence. (This can be confirmed by the subsitution $x=15+y^2$.)

Comment: I see, Thank you for it.

Comment: If you make the substitution $u = \sqrt{x}$ you get the integral $2\int \frac{\log(2\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{4+u})u}{\sqrt{u^2 - 15}}\,du$ which [WA can evaluate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+2ln%282sqrt%282%29+%2B+sqrt%284%2Bu%29%29u%2Fsqrt%28u%5E2-15%29), and you end up with a pretty nasty expression with several elliptic integrals.

Comment: By the change $u=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{x}}/2\sqrt{2}$ I arrive to the this form which seems better $\displaystyle 4\int_{\frac 14(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})}^1\frac{\sqrt{64u^4-64u^2+1}}{u+1}\,du$ but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: We can factorize to $\dfrac{\sqrt{au^2-1}\sqrt{\bar au^2-1}}{u+2\sqrt{2}}$ with $a=4\pm\sqrt{5}$ and maybe introduce some $\operatorname{dn}$ Jacobi function, but again I'm not familiar with this...

Comment: @DMcMor, the original problem on throwing into wolfram gives the nesty primitive in terms of Elliptical expression like you mentioned. So, matching your result seems the problem has no any elementary primitive.

Comment: @zwim, Thank you for hint. However, still  I cannot make progress with problem

Comment: Well, me neither! Guess we have to wait for the next issue of RMM next month...

Comment: I have been following this facebook group of RMM  since few years however, some of the proposals are remained unsolved. We can at least hope for the best.